# how to print only columns with a specific value

Tags: shell, awk, gawk

I have a file with column-separated values, the first row is shown here as columns titles for the next rows with real data. The real set of columns is considerably longer than in this example, btw, which is why I would like to automatize the job I need to do.

```
main-cat    ID  AFFIL   PERM    FF  PLAN    
ACA yes EDU yes no  no
ACA yes EDU no  yes no
ACA yes EDU no  no  yes
```

What I need is to extract, for every row, those columns with a value other than "no". Moreover I then want such a column to be printed on the format:

column title=row value

Example: the three examples rows above should be printed as:

```
main-cat=ACA ID=yes AFFIL=EDU PERM=yes 
main-cat=ACA ID=yes AFFIL=EDU FF=yes
main-cat=ACA ID=yes AFFIL=EDU PLAN=yes
```

My best suggestion is an endless list of conditions (there are MANY columns), saying that if column1 is not "no", print "main-cat="+row-value, if column 2 is not not "no", print "ID="+row-value. But surely there must be a more efficient way to achieve this? I use (g)awk and/or shell script.
Would be grateful for any suggestions.

Comment: What do you want printed if all fields are "no"? A blank line? Nothing? Something else?

Comment: Well I know in advance that some fields will always have a value other than no. Should that not be the case I'd probably just put a warning for myself to notice this row: "Warning: empty row".

Answer (score 2):

I'd say

```
awk 'NR == 1 { split($0, colnames); next } { sep = ""; for(i = 1; i <= NF; ++i) if($i != "no") { printf("%s%s=%s", sep, colnames[i], $i); sep = OFS } print "" }' filename
```

That is

```
NR == 1 {                                      # in the first line
  split($0, colnames)                          # remember column names
  next                                         # do nothing else
}
{                                              # in all other lines:
  sep = ""                                     # reset separator token
  for(i = 1; i <= NF; ++i) {                   # wade through fields
    if($i != "no") {                           # for those that aren't "no"
      printf("%s%s=%s", sep, colnames[i], $i)  # print them with the remem-
                                               # bered column name
      sep = OFS                                # set sep to OFS here so that
                                               # the fields will have a
                                               # separator in front, starting
                                               # with the second
    }
  }
  print ""                                     # when done, add newline.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
NR == 1 {
    for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {
        title[i] = $i
    }
    next
}

{
    for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {
        if ($i != "no") {
            printf(" %s=%s", title[i], $i)
        }
    }
    printf("\n")
}
```

Given your input file it generates the output you seek:

```
c:\> gawk -f temp.awk temp_in.txt
 main-cat=ACA ID=yes AFFIL=EDU PERM=yes
 main-cat=ACA ID=yes AFFIL=EDU FF=yes
 main-cat=ACA ID=yes AFFIL=EDU PLAN=yes

c:\>
```